# No MOTD on Ubuntu 14.04...?

Tags: ssh, motd

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. When I SSH, there is no MOTD (and yes, I have the appropriate command set in sshd_config).

I read a bunch of tutorials about setting up MOTD, but I realized that while I have /etc/update-motd.d, there is not /etc/motd file nor a /var/run/motd file.

How can I set these up so that I can get a MOTD via SSH?

Comment: Does `sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/` display the expected information?

Comment: Yes, it does. Though I don't see that after ssh login...

Comment: Check if in `/etc/pam.d/login` are present two uncommented lines that start with `session    optional   pam_motd.so`

Comment: Yes, there are two uncommented lines: `session    optional   pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate` and `session    optional   pam_motd.so`

Comment: Could you check if `PrintMotd` and `UsePAM` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` are set to yes?

Comment: `PrintMotd yes` was in there, but nothing about `UsePAM`.

Comment: Sorry, for late. Try adding `UsePAM yes` and let's see if it fix the problem. Also, please could you add @Letizia in your comment otherwise I will not get notification.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On a base install of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, simply drop the message you want in:

```
/etc/motd
```

By default, the MOTD will appear at the end of the other dynamic MOTD content. For example, here's the output from a Vagrant ubuntu/trusty64 (v20150506.0.0) box with a /etc/motd file added:

```
$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-52-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Thu May 14 20:06:56 UTC 2015

  System load:  0.39              Processes:           78
  Usage of /:   2.8% of 39.34GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 24%               IP address for eth0: 10.0.2.15
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


#####################################
Howdy! This message is from /etc/motd
#####################################

Last login: Thu May 14 20:06:56 2015 from 10.0.2.2
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

That's all there is to it if you're working on a system with the default settings.

---

*Some other troubleshooting notes:*

- Using "/etc/motd" is a change from earlier versions. Recommendations for 12.02 were to use "/etc/motd.tail". That doesn't work in 14.04.2.
- Other recommendations I've seen include changing some values in "/etc/ssh/sshd_config". In case those have been altered, here's the defaults that work:

  ```
  UsePAM yes
  PrintMotd no
  ```
- Likewise, here are the defaults for the `/etc/pam.d/login` I've seen referenced:

  ```
  session    optional   pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
  session    optional   pam_motd.so
  ```

That's everything I've seen referenced for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add:

```
 UsePAM yes
```

in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` as suggested in this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/543767) and in [Can't configure MOTD properly in Ubuntu 10.04 Server (update-motd command not found)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1511007)

> With UsePAM enabled, PAM will automatically update the MOTD and print
>   it for you when you log in. You have to disable PrintMOTD or SSH will
>   print it as well, so you'll see it twice, which is annoying.

I'm not sure about this, but in case you get motd twice, you should set `PrintMOTD` to no.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following  line to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` :

```
session    optional   pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because one of the scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d` failed to run (giving a non-zero exit code). Fixing it made MOTD start appearing again.

If you're unsure which one it is, just append a line `exit 0` to all scripts in that directory.

I noticed this on my machines running Ubuntu Disco and Debian Buster, but I am confident that it's applicable on Ubuntu Trusty (and even Precise).