# Message of the day at /etc/motd.tail not working

Tags: 14.04, motd

As detailed on AskUbuntu (multiple threads), I am trying to change my **message of the day**.

This is my edit:

```
luis@Terminus:/etc$ cat /etc/motd.tail
 ____                    _        _         ____
/ ___|  ___  _ __   __ _| | __ _ (_) ___   / ___|  ___ _ ____   ____ _
\___ \ / _ \| '_ \ / _` | |/ _` || |/ _ \  \___ \ / _ \ '__\ \ / / _` |
 ___) | (_) | |_) | (_| | | (_| || | (_) |  ___) |  __/ |   \ V / (_| |
|____/ \___/| .__/ \__,_|_|\__,_|/ |\___/  |____/ \___|_|    \_/ \__,_|
            |_|                |__/
luis@Terminus:/etc$ sudo login
Terminus nombre: luis
Contraseña:
Último inicio de sesión: dom jul 26 23:01:33 CEST 2015 en tty1
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-58-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

luis@Terminus:~$ ls /etc/motd.tail -la
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 372 jul 26 23:01 /etc/motd.tail
```

Excuse me, my Ubuntu is in spanish, but I think the needed part is clear: the file `/etc/motd.tail` is **ignored**.

What else could I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong file. The correct file is `/etc/motd`.

From `man motd` :

> The  contents  of  /etc/motd  are  displayed  by pam_motd(8) after a
>   successful login but just before it executes the login
>          shell.
>
> The abbreviation "motd" stands for "message of the day", and this file has been traditionally used  for  exactly  that  (it
>          requires much less disk space than mail to all users).
>
> On  Debian  GNU/Linux,  the  content of /run/motd.dynamic is also displayed.  This file is generated by /etc/init.d/motd at
>          boot.

Comment: You are right, heemayl. I have found the reason : «Using "/etc/motd" is a change from earlier versions. Recommendations for 12.02 were to use "/etc/motd.tail". That doesn't work in 14.04.2.». Extracted from here: http://askubuntu.com/a/623785/109008 . A bit awkward this continuous change in config files between versions, but at least `man motd` is supposed to show the actual paths. Thanks you.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Glad i could help  :)