# Ubuntu 15.10 update-motd.d not affects the MOTD

Tags: 12.04, command-line, login, 15.10, motd

I added a new file `80_own-motd` to the `/etc/update-motd.d` directory on my Ubuntu 15.10 Server.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo ">>>>>>Welcome to my Ubuntu Server<<<<<<<<<<
------------Questions to me@me.com--------------"
```

The output of the `sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/` shows the expected messages. When I restart the Server it shows the same message as before. :/
Here you can see my Folder Structure (`80_own-motd` is my new file):

```
/etc/update-motd.d$ ls -la
insgesamt 44 
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 23 09:00 . 
drwxr-xr-x 125 root root 12288 Jan 22 06:47 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1224 Jan 13 15:03 00-header
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1358 Feb 20  2014 10-help-text
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    46 Apr 30  2015 50-landscape-sysinfo -> /usr/share/landscape/landscape-sysinfo.wrapper
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   140 Jan 23 09:00 80-own_motd
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   149 Aug 22  2011 90-updates-available
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   299 Apr 12  2014 91-release-upgrade
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   142 Aug 22  2011 98-fsck-at-reboot
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   144 Aug 22  2011 98-reboot-required
```

Output from "grep motd /etc/pam* -R"

```
/etc/update-motd.d$ grep motd /etc/pam* -R
/etc/pam.d/login:# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
/etc/pam.d/login:# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
/etc/pam.d/login:session    optional   pam_motd.so  motd=/run   /motd.dynamic noupdate
/etc/pam.d/login:session    optional   pam_motd.so
/etc/pam.d/sshd:# This includes a dynamically generated part from  /run/motd.dynamic
/etc/pam.d/sshd:# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
/etc/pam.d/sshd:session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
/etc/pam.d/sshd:session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
```

Please help me :)

Comment: Please eidt your post to include the output of `grep motd /etc/pam* -R`

Comment: @muru it´s done :)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly likely you need to add `UsePAM no` to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. That solved the issue for me.

Also see [No MOTD on Ubuntu 14.04...?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538732/no-motd-on-ubuntu-14-04)