# Where is motd on modern Ubuntu systems?

Tags: motd

There is another question which covers some suggestions for changing the motd on modern ubuntu systems which do not have /etc/motd.

However, the other question does not ask (or tell) where the current Ubuntu MOTD is being stored. Where is it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the current Ubuntu MOTD"? The system information from Landscape?

Comment: AFAIK it's generated dynamically, using the scripts in /etc/update-motd.d/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Traditionally , [Unix `motd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motd_(Unix)) would live in `/etc/motd` directory.[RHEL still does that](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/223483). Ubuntu on the other hand places login messages in  `/etc/update-motd.d/` directory.

```
$ ls /etc/update-motd.d/                                                        
00-header*     90-updates-available*  98-fsck-at-reboot*
10-help-text*  91-release-upgrade*    98-reboot-required*
```

Each of these scripts is responsible for [dynamically assembling](https://askubuntu.com/a/105691/295286) the whole message and provide specific parts.

It is still , however, [possible to create a custom message in /etc/motd](https://askubuntu.com/a/623785/295286) and place it into `/etc/motd` . File itself doesn't exist, but you just have to create it.

Here's how I tested it:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo  "THIS IS A TEST" >> /etc/motd'                             
[sudo] password for xieerqi:
```

Comment: I did this, but it still puts the dynamic information at the top of the message. The stuff in my custom motd was appended at the end.

Comment: Yes, that's the normal behavior. Do you want to remove the other information and only display your own message ?

Comment: Yes, I want to only display my message.

Comment: In that case, just remove those scripts in `/etc/update-motd.d/` . Maybe save them somewhere else